# Securing Azure function executions origin when hosted on a Consumption Plan

Tags: azure, azure-functions

Do you have any idea on how to secure Azure functions executions origin when hosted on a Consumption Plan?

Let's assume we have 2 Azure Functions with several functions inside each of them, these 2 Azure Functions being hosted on 2 different Consumption Plans: do you know how it would be possible to ensure that only functions from one Azure Function can launch execution of functions in the other Azure Function?

As ip address filtering cannot be ensured for Consumption Plan (except by adding the whole Datacenter IP range), I am looking for a way to harden the execution of the functions.

Thank you

Comment: Authentication through shared secrets, client certificates or OAuth tokens can be implemented. Apart from running your functions in a dedicated environment (ASE, expensive), you can't know the addresses before hand, or they'll be shared with others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consumption Plan does not offer network isolation. You may want to look at Premium plan which allows your functions to run inside dedicated Vnet , thus offering network isolation.